# Div 100% height minus fixed size

Tags: html, css

I need to create the following structure:

```
[        30px height        ]
[ full height (100% - 30px) ]
```

Is it possible to achieve this solely with HTML5 + CSS3 (cross-browser)? This DIVs must not overlap.

Comment: what are de names of the divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with absolute positioning without using the experimental and [not widely supported](http://caniuse.com/calc) `calc` feature, the following works in every browser since 1999:

### HTML

```
<div id="root">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="rest"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#root {
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    background:blue;
    position:relative;
}
#top {
    height:24px;
    position:absolute;
    background:green;
    border:3px solid maroon;
    width:100%;
}
#rest {
    border:3px solid yellow;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:30px;
    bottom:0;    
    background:red;
}
```

<kbd>[**JSfiddle sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/w3S5k/)</kbd>

Comment: Wow, how nice and elegant. Thanks, i will try this!

Comment: It's what absolute positioning was invented for  :)

Comment: So what's the trick? Using `absolute` without specifying a position in `#top` and specifying `top:<offset>px` in `#rest` in cunjunction with `position:absolute` as well?

Comment: Now in 2017 you should just use `calc` as it now [is supported by every active browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).

Answer (score 3):

Use `calc()` in CSS

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DWfHD/1/)

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

div.black {
    background: #000;
    height: calc(100% - 30px);
}

.red {
    height: 30px; 
    background: #f00;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DWfHD/) (Missed out the `30px div` on top)

Comment: `calc` doesn't work in IE8 and requires prefixes in most WebKit browsers. [Reference](http://caniuse.com/calc).

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Many properties doesn't work, so simply we leave supporting old browsers or we use workarounds like pie :) as OP didn't mention about old browser support, also he specifically mentioned **HTML5+CSS3** and I posted my solution :)

Comment: Well my solution works identically in HTML4 and CSS1, including IE6 and I think even IE5.5. I know which one I would prefer given IE8's current market share  ;)

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Well, it's upto OP to decide what to use and what not to :)