# css vertically alignment inside a liquid height div?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

My css positioning nightmare continues

```
<div id="divLeft">LEFT</div>
<div id="divRight">
    <div id="divTop">TOP</div>
    <div id="divCenter"><img id="imgC" src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Primo_Icons/PNG/128x128/button_blue_repeat.png"/></div>
    <div id="divBottom">BOTTOM</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#imgC{
    width:100px;
    vertical-align:middle; // doesn't work?
}
```

How can I keep the image vertically centered (note: parent div has a liquid height).

[Here is jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bonaca/gpwD4/15/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position:absolute` with a negative margin, [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/gpwD4/16/).

```
#imgC{
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-50px;
}
```

I also see you're using `calc` for aligning the top/center/bottom divs, [you can also achieve that without `calc` and still have IE6 compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16852772/1729885). `calc` only works in [very recent browsers](http://caniuse.com/calc).

Comment: Niels, thanks, but in your example horizontal alignment is gone. I tried the same technique (`left:50%...`) - doesn't work.

Comment: There was no `position:relative` on the parent, didn't see that. [Updated fiddle here with both horizontal and vertical centering](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/gpwD4/17/).